# Change cell background color on Google Sheets based on percentage

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I’m familiar with the conditional formatting tool on Google Sheets, but for what I’m working on, coding it on script editor would be much more ideal. I’m trying to learn Apps Script basics but sometimes I can’t put the stuff together coherently. I have zero coding experience and any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Situation:**

I need to change the background color of `Column C` and `Column W` based on the percentage shown in `Column W` cells

Any edits I make from columns `F` though `T` will update `Column W`’s percentage. `Column W` will have a percentage ranging from `0-.99`.

I’d like for this to be the colors based on value. Exact colors are in parentheses.

```
0 = White
<=.33 = Red (#e67c73)
<=.66 = Orange (#f6b26b)
<=.99 = Yellow (#ffd966)
```

Comment: So what have you tried to get this to work and why is a script solution better than the inbuilt formatter?

Comment: @JamesD I have a view on only active Rows/Columns( ~34 rows). Built in formatting wont apply the to new rows that I add. When I try to set the conditional range as B2:B, it defaults to B2:B34 and won't apply to future/new rows.

Comment: How are you adding the rows? I can't recreate the issue.

Comment: @Diego If you scroll all the way to the bottom of the spreadsheet, there is a "Add *Insert number* more rows at the bottom." Should be at the bottom left of the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var edtSht='sheetname';
  var ss=e.source;
  var rg=e.range;
  var sh=rg.getSheet();
  var row=rg.getRow();
  var col=rg.getColumn();
  if(sh.getName()==edtSht && col>=6 && col<=20){
    var drg=sh.getDataRange();
    var bA=drg.getBackgrounds();
    var vA=drg.getValues();
    for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
      if(vA[i][22]==0){
        bA[i][2]='ffffff';
        bA[i][22]='ffffff';
      }
      if(vA[i][22]>0 && vA[i][22]<=.33){
        bA[i][2]='#e67c73';
        bA[i][22]='#e67c73';
      }
      if(vA[i][22]>.33 && vA[i][22]<=.66){
        bA[i][2]='#f6b26b';
        bA[i][22]='#f6b26b';
      }
      if(vA[i][22]>.66 && vA[i][22]<=.99){
        bA[i][2]='#ffd966';
        bA[i][22]='#ffd966';
      }
    }
    drg.setBackgrounds(bA);
  }
}
```

Of course you can modify it to do this for each row as needed.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to put this together! I tried using this and the output when I tried to run/save it was: TypeError: Cannot call method "source" of undefined.

Comment: You can't run this from the Editor.  You have to generate an onEdit(e) event and set the sheetname.

Comment: This works. You are a genius and I will name my first child after you. Thank you so much!